# Should conditional logic be always coded via type system where possible?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, type-systems, polymorphism, conditions

I have a choice.

Option 1:

```
public class Sample
{
    bool IsRelevant { get; set; }
}
```

Option 2:

```
public class Sample
{
}

public class RelevantSample : Sample
{
}
```

Is there a clear well-known rule how to make this decision?

My research: I have heard about "Replace Conditional with Polymorphism" refactoring before, but it usually deals with large switch statements:

https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234458/do-polymorphism-or-conditionals-promote-better-design

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866873/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism-nice-in-theory-but-not-practical

There is a somewhat related question that describes a different situation (flag as a method argument rather than part of a domain entity): [Is it wrong to use a boolean parameter to determine behavior?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147977/is-it-wrong-to-use-a-boolean-parameter-to-determine-behavior)

Comment: You should use both options with caution, as both will potentially break Likov's substitution principle.

Comment: This is a bit off topic, but `bool IsRelevant { get; set; }` is wrong; it should either be `bool IsRelevant { get; protected set; }` or, better yet, `bool IsRelevant { get; private set; }` and be initialized via the constructor.

Comment: @MikeNakis I agree, just wanted to keep the sample minimal.

Comment: This question is very confusing. Who is choosing to act differently depending on whether the sample is relevant? Is it the class itself, or the code using the class? Option 1 seems to imply the latter, whereas option 2 implies the former.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it wrong to use a boolean parameter to determine behavior?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/147977/is-it-wrong-to-use-a-boolean-parameter-to-determine-behavior)

Comment: @MikeNakis: mutable data structures are still useful for many situations and are not necessarily "wrong".

Comment: @whatsisname I do not deny that mutable classes are useful, but in this particular case the "IsRelevant" property appears to reflect such a fundamental characteristic of the entity, that the property could be eliminated if a subclass was to address this characteristic, as per the OP's example. So, to me it looks like an immutable property.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the language choice is irrelevant. What is important in making the decision is how the information is used.

If `Sample`s behave differently depending on the value of `isRelevent` then it absolutely makes sense to break it up into three (not two) classes. The base `Sample` class, a `RelevantSample` class and a `IrrelevantSample` class. All sample objects would be instantiated from one of the two later classes (thus following the heuristic that base classes should be abstract.) Other objects can then inform sample objects of events without concerning themselves over whether the sample is relevant or not.

However, if it's more a matter of other objects behaving differently depending on the relevancy of the sample, then you would want to go with option 1 and make isRelevant a field that can be queried.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds like a very clear rule :). My situation is of second variety.

Comment: I'd add that you would also go for a single class if ``isRelevant`` is a calculated property such as ``return  m_relevance > THRESHOLD ; ``. Even if it is not the case now, it might be later on. As usual, a design is the result of choices :)

Answer (score 13):

You have two good answers already; a third reason to stick with the property is that the pattern you are describing is a "one shot" pattern. Everything goes pear shaped when you add a second Boolean. We begin with:

```
public class Sample
{
    public bool IsRelevant { get; protected set; }
}
```

and we refactor this into:

```
public abstract class Sample {}
public class RelevantSample : Sample {}
public class IrrelevantSample : Sample {}
```

And now we realize, oh, wait, samples can also be frobby or antifrobby:

```
public abstract class Sample 
{
    public bool IsFrobby { get; protected set; }
}
public class RelevantSample : Sample {}
public class IrrelevantSample : Sample {}
```

And now how do we move *that* into the type system?

```
public class RelevantFrobbySample : RelevantSample {}
public class RelevantAntifrobbySample : RelevantSample {}
public class IrrelevantFrobbySample : IrrelevantSample {}
public class IrrelevantAntifrobbySample : IrrelevantSample {}
```

And now I want to make a method that takes only frobby samples. How do I do it?

Single inheritance languages require you to choose your "inheritance pivot" **extremely carefully** because you only get one shot at it.

Comment: Good point and even when C# gets traits I would probably avoid using them for reason given by @Telastyn.

Comment: The solution is to use Interfaces instead of Abstract classes. I consider inheritance of implementation a code smell. (My last sentence can spawn a whole conversation which I'm happy to have, but isn't appropriate here. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Not in C#.

Encoding implied behavior into types is evil in C# and similar languages, because the only way to get info out of the type is `if x is T` sort of checks (or trickery with `dynamic`, or reflection). So any change to it (adding a new variant, changing the behavior of a type) mean you get to go into all your consumers, violating the Open Closed Principle.

Comment: 1. I tagged it to get syntax highlighting, info about other languages would be appreciated.

Comment: 2. What if I say that change is very unlikely?

Comment: @den - in languages with pattern matching, or ingrained dynamic dispatch, it works better, but I don't have enough experience there to say which way to go.

Comment: @den - change is inevitable.

Comment: Well, it should get better syntax-wise in C#7 with it's pattern matching. I was wondering about mathematical / philosophical /theoretical side of things :).

Comment: "the only way to get info out of the type is `if x is T`" - but that's the whole point. You should *not* get the info out of the type to begin with (see Daniel T's answer)

Comment: @L.Möller - yes, that _is_ the whole point. Encode data as data, not implicitly in the type.

Comment: Well, Objects are Data + Behavior. SOo I guess we disagree on whether the "Sample" is plain Data or more

Comment: @L.Möller - I'm not sure how you can look at two **empty** classes and say they're plain data.

Comment: I can't that's why I assumed that they're not. I think we kinda talk past each other. Don't think we can solve this.