# What should I call a flag to maybe disable some behaviour?

Tags: naming, naming-standards

Say I have a function:

```
def foo(x):
    if x % 2:
        do_something_with(x)

    return x
```

And I want to make the doing of something opt-outable:

```
def foo(x, maybe_do_something_with_x=True):
    if maybe_do_something_with_x:
        if x % 2:
            do_something_with(x)

    return x
```

That variable name is awful, but I'm not quite able to come up with something more concise.

What is the general practice?

Comment: Whilst not a duplicate [of this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/323554/are-all-boolean-arguments-flag-arguments-and-thus-a-code-smell), it's worth highlighting it. What to call the flag is a minor issue compared with the whole (bad) idea of introducing a flag in the first place. Just don't do it.

Comment: The context is that I have some auto updating of a field in a django model `.save()`, and I'd like to be able to not have it happen if for whatever reason I'm in the shell putting out fires, and don't want the updating to happen.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understood context correctly, but overriding django base `save` doesn't sound like something you want to do especially to disable something. Could you ask a question about your original problem, possibly on SO, so we could help the best way possible ?

Comment: [Overriding of those methods is exactly what you're meant to do](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods).  I've added automatic updating of a field in `.save()`, and have added the flag in question to the arguments to bypass the updating should one need to.

Comment: Ok, I understand better now. For some reason I thought you wanted to disable an update *in* django. Well my answer is the best I can provide you.

Comment: I've already voted it up.  :)  I'll be accepting at a later date if something better doesn't come along.

Answer (score 0):

> That variable name is awful, but I'm not quite able to come up with something more concise.

Long names aren't necessarily a problem as long as they explain well what is this variable. You could call it `enable_x` to stress the fact its a boolean that will enable a particular treatment. But using booleans to force an execution path should be avoided whenever possible.

> What is the general practice ?

To avoid this kind of flag entirely. The most elegant design is to refactor using classes and overrides :

```python
class A:
    def foo(x):
        start_of_foo(x)
        bar(x)
        remaining_of_foo(x)

    def bar(x):
        pass

class B(A):
   def bar(x):
       do_something_with(x)
```

Then you can use `B()` or `A()` based on situation

Alternatively, if you are reluctant to use a class for this :

```python
def foo(x, mybar=bar):
    start_of_foo(x)
    mybar(x)
    remaining_of_foo(x)

def bar(x):
    pass

def specific_bar(x):
    do_something_with(x)
```

Comment: Worth noting that the library in question [uses flags such as these](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2a431db0f5e91110b4fda05949de1f158a20ec5b/django/db/models/base.py#L663) in the method I'm overriding.  I like the idea of subclassing though.